# How do I get publishers and agents to read my full book?

Tags: publishing

My problem is that my first few chapters are decent but the last few chapters of my book are superb writing that is capable of becoming famous.

How do I get publishers and agents to read my full book?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewrite the first few chapters and make them superb.  There is no law that says that yesterday's writing has to stay in the story.  If the story's definition has improved, or if you yourself have improved in writing skill and creative voice, then throw away yesterday's inferior work.  Make every page shine!

Publishers and Agents are like every other potential fan of your work.  The only tool you have for seducing them into reading the next page, is the excellence of all the pages they've already read.

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is any other way. The start sells the book. Realistically if you were capable of writing such a great ending, you will be able to write a great beginning. In fact, if you really hit your stride at the end and do not have a major time constraint you should write all of it up to the same level. Would make selling the book much easier...

Answer (score 5):

Agents and publishers are irrelevant. The real question here is: How do you get **readers** to read your full book? And the answer to that is that your book won't leave the book store if the beginning is not  superb. And that is why agents and publishers read only the beginning: because the reader will.

---

Also, congratulations on a healthy dose of overestimation of your own abilities. Research has shown that it's not ability but bigheadedness that better predict success. Bad writing has consistently made the bestseller lists – in fact most beststelling authors are at best mediocre stylists –, but self-doubt rarely has. So I'm sure you're gonna go far.

Comment: Cant tell if that second paragraph is sarcastic or not...

Comment: @Jimmery Me neither.

Comment: BWAHAHAH. This had me laughing for a good minute.
I cant tell if I was just insulted or praised.
But whatever, Arrogance is simply a byproduct of superiority.

Comment: Both. I do think that a firm belief in one's superiority is useful, while I personally like people best who don't flaunt it. Being superior and not acting superior don't exclude each other, and since as a writer you will be a brand or celebrity, some modesty might make you more likeable. People love Tolkien's books also because of their author's character. That said, I have also seen too many people who thought themselves great artists but simply weren't. The claim of greatness in your question lacks proof and is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Hook your readers from the first sentence and don't let them go until the very end. You can't tell literary professionals to hang in there till your story gets interesting: you'll be tagged as an amateur straight away. Do your homework. Serious writers know this stuff. I wish you well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider dropping the first few chapters.  Most books can stand some tough-love editing, and if the first few chapters don't stand out as great, even to you, the author, maybe it means they are dispensable.  It might be that you needed them to get your start on the story, but --like the sketch on the canvas that the artist later paints over --they aren't that important to the final product.

You could also see if they might work better if placed elsewhere in the book.  For instance, if the book is fairly linear, you might experiment with starting in the middle of the action instead.